# Многостраничный PDF из набора JPG - Coonvert

Tags: linux

Каким образом из нескольких файлов jpg/pdf указанных вручную можно сделать многостраничный pdf средствами утилиты convert?

```
exec("convert $url_convert $url_convert2");
```

Создает одностраничники

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот так

```
convert ./page{01..99}.jpg ./mydoc.pdf
```